# Reading in positive long integer values into an array

Tags: java, arrays, binary, integer, long-integer

I'm looking to read in a file of type .dat.  I do not know the size of the file, however I do know that the contents will be in the form of

```
111000111
0101
0100
1
0011
110
0010
101
0001
11
0000
```

Current what I have is below

```
public static void readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File file = new File(fileName);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
    {
        fis.read(bytes);
    }


    String[] value = new String(bytes).split("\\s+");


    numbers = new int[value.length];


    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(value[i]);
    }





    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }

} // end of import file
```

The output of the file is list below.  As you can see, if a number begins with a 0 (or multiple), it is removed.

```
111000111
101
100
1
11
110
10
101
1
11
0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Mike

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: he wants to know how to prevent truncation of the leading zeros in the numbers.

Comment: If you want to keep leading zeros, then you don't want `Integer`s. Just store them as `String`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problems with leading zeros, than you should not use the Integer.parseInt

Holding an array of Strings would be better for this case.

```
numbers = new String[value.length];
```

and

```
numbers[i] = value[i];
```

If later, you want to use the array contents as integers in any method, you may use Integer.parseInt there.

Comment: Well, I guess my trouble with that is, I need to keep the values as they are.  Such that 0001 remains 0001 once converted to an int to do necessary conversions.  So Integer.parseInt is not working as I need it to.  Is there a way to do padding such that I am able to keep the zeros?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're parsing your values into integers

```
Integer.parseInt(value[i])
```

Use this instead:

```
String[] values = new String[value.length];


for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
{
    values[i] = value[i];
}
```